# Runtime.getRuntime.exec() problem

Tags: java, user-interface

hi
I am trying to execute the Runtime.getRuntime.exec("ffmpeg -i inputfile image2 imagefile");

the input file in my code is the video file and i'm selecting the video file through the GUI

and i store it in a variable.So how can i use a variable name in place of the String?.It does

not work if i substitute the variable.
Any help is greatly app

Answer (score 2):

```
String inputfileVariable = ...; << maybe you calculate, maybe get from some GUI component
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("ffmpeg -i " +  inputfileVariable + " image2 imagefile");
```

There's no magic here, it's only a string.

Answer (score 2):

You need command array like this:

```
// i guess that ffmpeg is a command name and the reset are arguments
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"ffmpeg","-i",inputfileVariable,"image2", "imagefile"});
```